# null value when sending email via MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this MVC C# App and a controller where trying to send a email, but I always got this error

[image]

[image]

this is the code in my action´controller, it doesn´t receive any model so I add specific values

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index2()
        {
            try
            {

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add("valid_email@hotmail.com");
            mail.From = new MailAddress("valid_email@gmail.com");
            mail.Subject = "PruebaMVC";
            string Body = "PruebaMVC";
            mail.Body = Body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
            ("valid_email@gmail.com", "correctPWD");
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(mail);
                }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Exception in sendEmail:" + ex.Message);
            }

            return View();
        }
```

could you please tell what is wrong?

edit: this is the exception I got
[image]

Comment: What's the *actual* exception though? The value of `ex` - You're catching it, then throwing an `ArgumentNullException`

Comment: Put a breakpoint one line before `throw` and check the exception object `ex`

Comment: @degant thanks, just updated my question

Comment: Do a `ping smtp.gmail.com` from the machine where this code is running. From the exception it isn't able to resolve the hostname

Comment: @degant got the message: "could find the smtp.gmail.com host, verify and try again"

Comment: Then you'll have to find out why your machine isn't able to ping `smtp.gmail.com` while the rest of the world is able to

Comment: I guess you are behind a company firewall which does not allow gmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i have used below code and it's working fine for me and i have configured smtp in web.config

ContentType HTMLType = new ContentType("text/html");
NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(StringConstant.NetworkUserName, StringConstant.NetworkPwd);

```
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
            msg.To.Add(ToEmail);
            msg.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High;
            msg.Subject = Subj;

            msg.Body = strBody;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            if (attachement != null)
            {
                msg.Attachments.Add(attachement);
            }

            System.Net.Mail.AlternateView HTMLView = System.Net.Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(strBody, HTMLType);
            msg.From = new MailAddress(StringConstant.MailFrom); // Your Email Id

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(StringConstant.SmtpFrom, StringConstant.SmtpPort);
            client.Credentials = cred;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Send(msg);
```